# Scoutmaps iOS SDK pod seems to be missing public headers

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, skmaps

So I tried to update to scoutmap ios sdk 2.5.1 via pods and I'm getting the error:

****/Pods/ScoutMaps-iOS-SDKTools/SDKTools/Navigation/SKTNavigationManager+NavigationState.m:259:40: No visible @interface for 'SKRoutingService' declares the selector 'zoomToRouteWithInsets:'

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: This problem will be solved in the next update of the Scout SDK